# Till what level does a health pot out-heal ignite damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

The question is pretty self-explanatory. Did someone do the math to know till what level the healing pot out-heals ignite? Assume that there is no other damage applied an no other healing applied.

Notice, that when I say out-heal I mean that the champion will live even if he had 1 hp at the moment that hp pot and ignite started ticking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Healing Potions heal for 150 health over 15 seconds, i.e. 10 health per second
Champion regeneration is about 5 health over 5 seconds depending on the champion, i.e. 1 health per second

Ignite does 50 + 20 per level over 5 seconds, i.e. 10+4 per level per second and reduces healing by 50%.

That means if you are at 1hp a health potion won't save you at any level with a reduced healing of about 5-6 health per second compared to 14 damage per second but you can survive it if you have more than ~40hp on level 1.

Healing Potions against ignite are more of a last straw, not a reliable way to counteract it.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health_Potion
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ignite

Comment: If you're looking for a way to counter an ignite, use a Red Potion. It will instantly buff you 250hp (I think; Off memory). This will counter the health loss from ignite in early levels.

Comment: True, though how often do you carry a red potion around? :)

Comment: As an AD carry, if I see an ignite in the opposing lane and I'm playing an aggressive style myself, it's not too uncommon.

Comment: Ignite technically "out-damages" an HP pot at all levels since the duration is shorter than a full Hpot. With 50% heal debuff, an Hpot will only heal for 125 over 15 seconds, Ignite deals 130 over 5 seconds at just level 4. That's ~7 regen per second compared to 26 damage per second